# Shell: straightforward if statement seems not working

Tags: shell, inotify, file-comparison

I've written this shell script snippet:

```
while inotifywait -e modify $ENV_LOCATION/*.env
do
  md5sum $ENV_LOCATION/*.env > ./checksums_optwo.md5
  if [ -n "$(cmp ./checksums_opone.md5 ./checksums_optwo.md5)" ]
  then
    gdialog --msgbox "The files are different"
    md5sum $ENV_LOCATION/*.env > ./checksums_opone.md5
  else
    gdialog --msgbox "The files match"
  fi
done
```

However, I can’t quite figure out why `gdialog` is not prompted. Any ideas?

Comment: You have `gdialog` in both branches of the `if`. Does it work properly in one, but not the other; or in neither? Also, does `./checksums_opone.md5` exist beforehand? You're only creating it inside the `if`.

Comment: How are you causing the "modify" event?  Are you editing files in `$ENV_LOCATION` directly?  Is some other process changing them?

Comment: It doesn't work in neither ones

Comment: I'm opening a new terminal then I open a `vim`

Comment: And what event(s) does `inotifywait` report?

Comment: @Jordi, well, does the `gdialog` work without the `if` and `while` surrounding it? If it doesn't work in either branch of the `if`, it would hint that the problem isn't with the `if`, but somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You have `gdialog` in both branches of your `if` statement, so one of them will be run as long as `inotifywait` exits with a zero exit status. The `inotifywait` command will exit with a non-zero exit status if any of the files being watched are deleted (and you're not watching for deletion events).

To watch for deletion and modification of any of the files, use

```
inotifywait -e modify -e delete_self "$ENV_LOCATION"/*.env
```

To compare two files with `cmp` and react to the result:

```
if cmp -s file1 file2; then
    echo 'files are the same'
else
    echo 'files are different'
fi
```